# jquery find all elements with the same class, stop after all found

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide and show certain table rows on button click.

the table rows looks something like.

```
<tr class="head">
   <td>Always</td>
   <td>Visible</td>
   <td><button></td>
</tr>

   <tr class="bg-detail hidden">
      <td>Hidden Col 1</td>
      <td>Hidden Col 2</td>
      <td>Hidden Col 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="bg-detail hidden">
      <td>Hidden Col 1</td>
      <td>Hidden Col 2</td>
      <td>Hidden Col 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="bg-detail hidden">
      <td>Hidden Col 1</td>
      <td>Hidden Col 2</td>
      <td>Hidden Col 3</td>
   </tr>

<tr class="head">
   <td>Always</td>
   <td>Visible</td>
   <td><button></td>
</tr>
```

so, in short, the bg-detail hidden tr's are all childrens of the first tr.head. 
as for the jquery I have:

```
$('.btn-showdetail').on('click', function(){
     //console.log('btn-showdetail clicked');
     //$("i", this).toggleClass("mdi-menu mdi-menu-open");
     $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.bg-detail').toggleClass("hidden shown");
});
```

but this only toggles the next bg-detail it's able to find. I found nextUntil in the wiki but didn't get this to work with my example.

https://jsfiddle.net/1keyup/f8nbjxdy/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nextUntil` but you must specify both parameters:

```
$(this)
  .closest('tr')
  .nextUntil('tr.head', 'tr.bg-detail')
  .toggleClass("hidden shown");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9c3L6rd/

Comment: Hi Matei, thanks for the answer, when using nextAll like your example, all get toggled https://jsfiddle.net/1keyup/f8nbjxdy/3/

Comment: thank you very much! I think I missunderstood the nextUntil for some reason.